# Changing background colour when IntVar is higher than 5 (tkinter/python)

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem is that I am trying to make the background colour to change when the string variable is higher than 5. 
this is the code:

```
colour_p1="White"
kills_p1 = IntVar()
kills_p1.set(0)
def kill_count_p1():
    kills_p1.set(kills_p1.get()+1)
if kills_p1.get() >= 5:
    colour_p1 = "Yellow"
Label(master, textvariable=kills_p1, bg=colour_p1, font=("Courier", 20)).grid(column = 4, row=2)
```

I have tried a few different ways like "if", but it keeps it on the same colour all the time. I want the background to be yellow when the variable "kills_p1" is higher than 5. 
ps. this is only a part of the project and not the whole

Comment: You have no logic in that sample, that looks for values > 5, nor any logic to change bg from anything but "White". Is there any more code?

Comment: yes there is, but it has nothing to do with the problem i've got. I removed the code i had about my problem a bit earlier. I will add it back again so it makes more sense. :)

Comment: in which widget are you trying to change color? please be a little more specific.

Comment: in:  "if kills_p1.get() >= 5:    colour_p1 = "Yellow"".  it is supposed to change "Label(..., bg=colour_p1" i'm sorry if i'm making you all confused! i'm pretty much a beginner at programming and tkinter, so i'm sorry.

Comment: You're missing the final quote on the first line: `colour_p1="White`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `kill_count_p1` you need to update the label's colour, otherwise it won't change:

```
def kill_count_p1():
    kills_p1.set(kills_p1.get()+1)
    if kills_p1.get() >= 5:
        colour_p1 = "Yellow"
        Label(master, textvariable=kills_p1, bg=colour_p1, font=("Courier", 20)).grid(column = 4, row=2)
```

Then, when you call `kill_count_p1`, you should update the label colour if `colour_p1` is greater or equal to 5.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, create a button:

```
button = tk.Button(root, text="click me", command=lambda:onclick1())
button.pack()
```

create the entry:

```
x=IntVar()

e=Entry(root, textvariable=x)
e.pack()
```

let the following be the function called using the button which changes the background after checking the variable:

```
def onclick1():
    x1=int(e.get())
    if x1<5:
        root.config(bg="white")
```